# Get IMG SRC via web scraping through cheerio with node.js

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, cheerio

Using an event-listener to GET [this](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/monk/) and cheerio to get the img src out of:

```
<div class="mainimage">
```

Current code:

```
var cheerio = require('cheerio'),
$ = cheerio.load(this.responseText);
console.log($('mainimage').attr('img'));
```

However it returns 'undefined'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need to have `.mainimage` (notice the dot) since that is how the jQuery syntax for selecting something with a particular class is. Then you want to access the `<img>` tag inside the `.mainimage` div. And finally we can read the src attribute from the image tag:

```
console.log($('.mainimage img').attr('src'));
```